# Connect to AWS using MQTT.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mqtt, paho

I want to design a web-page in which I can connect to AWS server. In python-Paho-mqtt, I can use the tls_set option to provide the security certificates and other stuff. How do I provide the same using MQTT.js? If I can't how do I run python-PAHO-MQTT from HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate management is all handled by the browser for Websocket connections, not the javascript client.

You would need to load your certificate into which ever browser keystore is being used and it will pick (or ask if multiple matches) the right one to send to the server when establishing the connection the same way it does for mutually secured https